# P element forces down other elements it's inside

Tags: html

Really not sure why this is happening, but it's very annoying as I can't seem to find the cause of it.

If I take the below HTML and add a P element inside the class="comments" div then it'll push down the entire class="ratingComments" div that it's inside. Even if I turn off margins and padding it'll still do it, why is this?

It'll probably make more sense to look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sz4fodqj/

I want the two divs in the center to be inline, but the P tag prevents this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nrthrn</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./res/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960styling.css" id="stylesheet">   
</head>



<div id="wrapper">
<body>

    <div class="headerBar">

        <img id="logo" src="./res/logo.png"/>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="pastEvents.html" accesskey="o">Past Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="c">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="form.html" accesskey="a">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>

        <a id="loginLink" href="login.html">Login</a>




    </div> <!-- end headerBar -->


    <div class="promoArea">
        <img id="bigLogo" src="./res/bigLogo.png"/>
    </div>





     <div class="eventsSearchBar">

        <p>Order By: </p>
        <select required="required" name="field4" class="selectfield">
                <option value="Advertise">Closest Date</option>
                <option value="Partnership">Furthest Date</option>
                <option value="General Question">Rating: High to Low</option>
                <option value="General Question">Rating: Low to High</option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <div class="pastEventsContentArea">

        <div class="pastEventRowContainer">
            <div class="pastEventContainer">

                <div class="dateWrapper">
                    <span class="day"><p id="daytext"><b>23rd</b></p></span>
                    <span class="month"><p id="monthtext"><b>May</b></p></span>

                </div>

                <div class="textWrapper">

                    <div class="title"><p id="eventTitle">ODESZA</p></div>
                    <div class="location"><p>Location</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="buttonWrapper">
                    <button id="moreInfoButton">Info</button>
                    <button id="moreInfoButton">Tickets</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="ratingComment">

                <div class="rating">

                </div>
                <div class="comments"><!--P CLASS HERE MAKES WEIRD THINGS HAPPEN--></div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="footerBar">

        <div class="footerLeft">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="pastEvents.html" accesskey="o">Past Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="c">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="form.html" accesskey="a">Contact Us</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footerRight">
            <img src="./res/facebook.png"/>
            <img src="./res/twitter.png"/>
            <img src="./res/instagram.png"/>
        </div>


    </div>

    <p id="copyright">Copyright 2017</p>



</body>
</div>




</html>
```

CSS

```
.pastEventsContentArea{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto; /*top right bottom left */
    padding-top: 20px;
/*  background-color: #ff6464;*/
    text-align: center;
}

.pastEventContainer{
    /*width: 45%;
    height: 30%;*/
/*    width: 55%;*/
    height: 120px;
/*     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 0%;
/*    margin-bottom: 10px;*/
/*    margin-right: 10px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #363636;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);


}

.pastEventContainer .dateWrapper{
    width: 20%;
    /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-family: opensans;
    color: black;

}

.pastEventContainer .textWrapper{
    width: 45%;
/*    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);*/
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: opensans;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.pastEventContainer .buttonWrapper{
    width: 30%;
/*    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);*/
    height: 100%;
    float: left;

}

.pastEventContainer .dateWrapper .day{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
/*    background-color: red;*/
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: opensans;


}

.pastEventContainer .dateWrapper .month{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
/*    background-color: indianred;*/
    font-size: 24px;
}

.pastEventContainer .dateWrapper #daytext{
    margin-top: 30%;
}

.pastEventContainer .dateWrapper #monthtext{
    margin-top: -10%;
}

.pastEventContainer .textWrapper .title{
/*    background-color: aqua;*/
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pastEventContainer .textWrapper .location{
/*    background-color: blue;*/
    margin-top: -20px;;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pastEventContainer .textWrapper p{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}


.pastEventContainer .buttonWrapper #moreInfoButton{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Porter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #242424;
    height: 30%;
    color: white;
    outline: 0;
    width: 75%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);*/
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.pastEventRowContainer .ratingComment{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #363636;
    border-width: 1px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.pastEventRowContainer .ratingComment .rating{
/*    background-color: red;*/
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.pastEventRowContainer .ratingComment .comments{
/*    background-color: aqua;*/
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: opensans;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.pastEventRowContainer .ratingComment a{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: `</body></div>` Something's really wrong already

Comment: change the p tag display to inline if it doesn't work put your code in jsfiddle so i can see what happening and i will fix it for you

Comment: It's already in a fiddle, see the OP. Thanks.

Comment: I've cleared everything up a bit, really not sure why these aren't in line. https://jsfiddle.net/sz4fodqj/3/

Answer (score 0):

p is block level element by default. You can use span instead or change the display properties of .comments in your css. This really depends on what you want to add in the div.

see
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: But why does this change the whole position of the div it's inside? Block just means that it'll take up the entire line of it's parent div, so why it's pushing the parent's parent div down by about 30 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is that `.ratingComment` has `display: inline-block;`. That forces the elements to change so that whatever elements you put inside `.comments` to be inline with the `.pastEventContainer`. Look at this for example https://jsfiddle.net/sz4fodqj/4/ where the div contains more text, still it's inline with the first div.